# Validate Android and Mac security

Tags: security

One of my Google account got compromised recently and since then I am hard pressed to find the reason behind the same. Is there a way to know what can be potential root cause of account being hacked.

Assuming credential is not guessed, brute-forced, peeked around or phished based on my recent activities, I am leaning towards possibility of an app/ browser vulnerability or device being compromised by potential keylogger/ malware. I am not sure what's the correct way to validate if my devices are safe specifically Android and MAC. For Windows machine, I am ok to reinstall complete OS thereby avoiding scans and any possibility of missing out something in scans. Any advise will be helpful.